# Não consigo instalar o ruby 2.3.2 no CentOS sem privilégio de root

Tags: ruby, centos

Estou precisando instalar o ruby num servidor com CentOS 6.5. Eu não tenho acesso root, então não posso usar o yum. Baixei o arquivo fonte, descompactei numa pasta chamada `~/software` e rodei

```
./configure && make && make install
```

Entretanto, apareceu o seguinte erro durante o `make install`:

```
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Já pesquisei na internet e não consegui encontrar uma solução para o meu problema.

Criei [um pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VEKHr4q9) com o log completo da instalação, caso isto seja necessário.

Comment: Geralmente o comando make install precisa ser executado como sudo mesmo, ele precisa instalar alguns binários em vários diretórios.

Existe uma razão para não usar RVM ou rbenv?

Comment: Eu não conhecia RVM ou rbenv antes do teu comentário. Na verdade, sequer conheço ruby direito. Eu só preciso desta linguagem para poder instalar o [linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/). Tentei instalar ambas as opções citadas no teu comentário, mas não consegui. O gpg dá Keyserver error no caso do RVM e a minha versão do git não foi compilado com (lib)curl-devel.

Comment: Então, como eu te disse, é comum usar sudo no `make install`, pra dizer a verdade, não me lembro de ter executado `make install` sem usar sudo. Qual seria o problema, no seu ponto de vista, em executar o comando com sudo? Não vejo como isso possa ser um problema:

`./configure && make && sudo make install`

Comment: Dê uma olhada aqui: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/difference-between-make-install-and-sudo-make-install

Comment: Eu não posso usar o sudo. Não tenho este privilégio neste servidor.